# Call function on another file JS React Native

Tags: react-native

**I have a Parent Class and Child Class but however i can't call a function on Parent Class from Child Class
It just for close the Modal and send a few data from Sorting on my modal. Sorry im a newbie on RN**

On OrderScreen i want to separate a modal and screen, so i call modal on another file JS, then on ModalSort.js i want to call back that function has been on his Parents or Order.screen.js

so many way i try but that modal still can't close, if i put onBackdropPress={() => ()} the modal can be close but no respon that i got

***Order.screen.js (a.k.a Parents.js)***

```
class OrderScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        visibleModal: null,
    };
};
exit = () => this.setState({ visibleModal: false });

_applySort = () => {
    this.setState({ visibleModal: false });
    this.onRefresh();
};
pressSort = () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 4 });

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerTop}>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 5} style={styles.bottomModal}>
                {this._renderModal()}
            </Modal>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 4} 
            style={styles.bottomModal}  onBackdropPress={() => {this.toggleModal();}}>
                {this._renderModalSort()}
            </Modal>



            <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 3} style={styles.bottomModal}>
                {this._renderModalFilter()}
            </Modal>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 2} style={styles.bottomModal}>
                {this._renderModalEmail()}
            </Modal>
            <NavigationEvents
                onWillFocus={this.willFocusAction} />
            <GeneralStatusBarColor backgroundColor="#FFF" barStyle="light-content" />
        </View>
    )
};

_renderModalSort = () => {
    return (
        <ModalSort 
            exit={() => {
                this.exit.bind(this);
            }}
        />
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ authOrder }) => {
const { orderSummary, error, loading, loadingSummary, loadingEmail, typeOfLocation, openNext, openList, closedList, closedNext } = authOrder;
return { orderSummary, error, loading, loadingSummary, loadingEmail, typeOfLocation, openNext, openList, closedList, closedNext };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getOrderSummary, getOpenOrderList, getClosedOrderList, sendEmailCsvAllOrder, logoutSession })(OrderScreen);
```

***ModalSort.js (a.k.a Child.js)***

```
class ModalSort extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        visibleModal: null,
    }
};
sorter = (isi) => this.setState({ sorted: isi });

_applySort = () => {
    this.setState({ visibleModal: false });
    // this.onRefresh();
};

render() {
    return(
            <View style={styles.modalContentSort}>
                <View style={styles.modalCenter}>
                <View style={styles.headerModel}>
                    <View style={styles.headerBack}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.exit()}}>
                            {/* <NavigationEvents onWillFocus={this.willFocusAction} /> */}
                            <Image style={styles.logoClose} source={require('../../assets/icons/iconClose.png')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerSort}>
                        <Text style={styles.textFilter}>Sort by</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textFilter}>SO Number</Text>
                <View style={styles.headerModel}>
                    <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(1)}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 1 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>
                                <Image style={styles.imageSort} source={require('../../assets/icons/iconNumberAscending.png')} />Ascending</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(2)}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 2 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>
                                <Image style={styles.imageSort} source={require('../../assets/icons/iconNumberDescending.png')} />Descending</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textFilter}>PO Customer</Text>
                <View style={styles.headerModel}>
                    <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(3)}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 3 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>
                                <Image style={styles.imageSort} source={require('../../assets/icons/iconNumberAscending.png')} />Ascending</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(4)}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 4 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>
                                <Image style={styles.imageSort} source={require('../../assets/icons/iconNumberDescending.png')} />Descending</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textFilter}>SO Date</Text>
                <View style={styles.headerModel}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(6)}>
                        <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 6 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>Newest</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(5)}>
                        <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 5 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>Oldest</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textFilter}>ETA</Text>
                <View style={styles.headerModel}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(8)}>
                        <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 8 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>Newest</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sorter(7)}>
                        <View style={styles.headerFilterItem}>
                            <Text style={this.state.sorted == 7 ? styles.headerBorderItemActive : styles.headerBorderItem}>Oldest</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonSort} onPress={this._applySort.bind(this)} >
                    <Text style={styles.textApply}>Apply</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
};

}
export default ModalSort;
```

Comment: Hi Rakha, please post your code directly using markdown code formatting, like `code` or 4 blanks at the beginning of the line. Please provide also a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help the SO community to reproduce your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close modal in `Parent` component from `Child` component:

   Your `Order.screen.js` has a mistake that make your program wouldn't run properly. When you use `this.exit.bind(this);`, it will return a callback, not a function. So, when you call `this.props.exit()` in `ModalSort.js`, it will call `exit` that actually shows nothing. To resolve this, you have 2 ways:

Order.screen.js

```
_renderModalSort = () => {
    return (
        <ModalSort 
            exit={this.exit.bind(this)}
        />
    )
};
```

or

```
_renderModalSort = () => {
    return (
        <ModalSort 
            exit={() => {
                this.exit();
            }}
        />
    )
};
```

2. Send data from sorting modal:

   Since you're using Redux, I suggest you create 2 actions. First action is to save your data to your state tree. Second one is to get those data. If you're not good at Redux, or you don't want to use it, you can try these step:

   - Initialize a variable to hold your data in `Parent`:

```
class OrderScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visibleModal: null,
        };
        this.data = null; // Your data goes here.
        /*
            You can store your data in state if you want to re-render when updating your data.
            this.state = {
                visibleModal: null,
                data: null
            }
        */
    }
}
```

- Create a function that save your data in `Parent`:

```
saveData(data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

- Pass that function to `Child`:

```
_renderModalSort = () => {
    return (
        <ModalSort 
            exit={() => {
                this.exit();
            }}
            saveData={(data) => {
                this.saveData(data);
            }}
        />
    )
};
```

- Lastly, you can call it from `Child`:

```
class ModalSort extends Component {
    sorting() {
        data = null; // Your data will be stored in this variable
        // You sorting function goes here
        this.props.saveData(data); // Save your data
    }
}
```

In case you have other works to do with saved data, you can modify the `saveData(data)` function in `Parent`.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: i've been try your code but to close modal still doesn't work, wait i'll update my full version code, thankyou